# Starting minikube in a Linux box requires authentication with Google Container Registry, why?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, virtualbox, minikube, google-container-registry

I am currently learning Kubernetes and I am playing with minikube tool. I have decided to install the tool in a VirtualBox instance that runs ubuntu/xenial64. I have created this instance using Vagrant and connected the instance through ssh.
I have installed minikube in accordance to the tool documentation - https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/.
When I run:
`$ minikube start`,
it failed with the following message:

```
$ minikube start
  minikube v1.11.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 (vbox/amd64)
✨  Using the docker driver based on existing profile
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Pulling base image ...
  Unfortunately, could not download the base image gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.10 
❗  In order to use the fall back image, you need to log in to the github packages registry
  Please visit the following link for documentation around this: 
    https://help.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-docker-for-use-with-github-packages#authenticating-to-github-packages

  Please either authenticate to the registry or use --base-image flag to use a different registry.
```

For some reason, in order to download minikube base image, it requires to authenticate to the gcr.io registry (Google Container Registry). The minikube documentation does mention nothing about this requirement. I am wondering why it happened. My understanding is it should not be mandatory to have a gsr account in order to use minikube. What am I doing wrong?
And what is the kicbase container (KIC) that minikube depends on?
I appreciate any help on this problem. Thank you.

Comment: can you run `docker pull gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.10`? if not, from what region are you trying to access? you may not have access there. you can try as well `wget gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.10`?.

Answer (score 7):

The first answer only explains part of the problem here. Your real problem is that you may need a proxy to communicate with `gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase` (or you are in a restricted network), as mentioned here: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/8124#issuecomment-628172092. This would be particularly true if you are running under a VPN.

In my case, I was able to `docker pull` the `kicbase` image *without the need of a proxy*:

```
$ docker pull gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.10
Trying to pull repository gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase ... 
v0.0.10: Pulling from gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase
Digest: sha256:f58e0c4662bac8a9b5dda7984b185bad8502ade5d9fa364bf2755d636ab51438
Status: Image is up to date for gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.10
```

And then, I was able to start the minikube with the following command:

```
$ minikube start --base-image=gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.10
  minikube v1.11.0 on Centos 7.8.2003
✨  Using the docker driver based on existing profile
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB) ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.18.3 on Docker 19.03.2 ...
    ▪ kubeadm.pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
  Verifying Kubernetes components...
  Enabled addons: default-storageclass, storage-provisioner
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube"
```

I would also recommend you to check the images you have on your docker (`docker images`) and delete (`docker rmi`) old versions of the `kicbase` (I had here versions v0.0.7, v0.0.8 and v0.0.10).

If even the manual `docker pull` does not solve the problem for you, you will really need to set up a proxy. There's a good reference on how to do that [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/vpn_and_proxy/).

**Edit:** added up some info on how to configure the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

It's not requesting you to login to gcr.io. It's falling back to use github registry for the image. And github require at least read permission to pull images. https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/8225